# Can I write inmultiple lines of input before I run python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can I do make a program accept many lines of prewritten input, something like this?

```
596
481
888
```

Comment: Yes. Show your own effort and code to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question).

Comment: Yes. Have a look at https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv, try to write some code and post it here, if you need help.

Comment: Do you mind being a little more specific? When you say "prewritten input" what do you mean? Are you talking about values that have already been assigned to a variable (such as an array)? Or are you asking how you assign values to a variable (or variables)? Or are you asking how to make a program accept user inputs from the console?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all you have to do is the following:

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
     print(arg)
```

Then when you run your program all you have to do is supply it command line arguments. Here is how that works:

```
python script.py foo bar baz
```

This will output:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

This is known as passing command line arguments.  Hope this helped you.

Just as some friendly advice I'd like to say that it is best to try to find the answer yourself first before posting here. (If you did that and you weren't able to then it is fine.)